# MVC 4 TextBoxFor HTML5 Currency

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to enter a number with decimal point into a text box, but I'm getting the error `You must enter a valid value`.

Can somebody please demonstrate how I modify the code below to ensure only a true price with decimal point and 2 decimal places can be entered into a form.

Also is it possible to prefix a field with a £ (&pound) character, but obviously on post the £ sign is omitted from the submitted value?

**Test.cs**

```
[DisplayName("Amount")]
public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, new { @class = "form-control", type = "number", placeholder = "Amount", required = "required" })
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? If so, I'd keep the currency symbol out of the textbox and use Bootstrap input groups http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic

Comment: Can you try with Html.EditorFor

Comment: I am indeed using Boostrap.

Comment: If I use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Amount, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Amount", required = "required" })` the css class does not apply.

Comment: You cannot add class to EditorFor, if you need to add class for some reason then use TextBoxFor instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up using the following code which is HTML5 compliant.

**Test.cs**

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Amount")]
[Range(0.01, 100000.00)]
public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, new { @class = "form-control", type = "number", step = "0.01", max = "100000.00", placeholder = "Amount", required = "required" })
```

This seems to have done the trick :-)

Answer (score 0):

Decorate the property with RegularExpression. 
Also I note you are wanting to emit Requiered attribute in you view control but it is best practice to do it in your entity, so the final decoration might look like this:

```
[Requiered,RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage = "Amount must be a number with two decimal place")]
public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

...and in your view use EditorFor

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Peso)
```

For currency symbol i'll go the way  @DavidG suggests